# Python - importing CSV into list to use for SSH/config changes

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, paramiko

My goal is to be able to SSH into around 200 routers and make a config change.  The change is dynamic based on location so i need to import a CSV which maps IP to the text(location) used for the change.

Right now it does SSH based on the imported CSV using the "ipaddresses" list but it then inputs all the variables from "facilities" list.  I would like to it just use a single variable out of the "facilities" list per IP address from the "ipaddresses" list.  I am not sure if i need to make a table or something else? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import csv 
    from netmiko import ConnectHandler

    with open('NID3.csv') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        ipaddresses = []
        facilities = []


        for row in readCSV:
            ipaddress = row[0]
            facility = row[1]

            facilities.append(facility)       
            ipaddresses.append(ipaddress)


    platform = 'cisco_ios'
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'

    for host in ipaddresses:
        device = ConnectHandler(device_type=platform, ip=host, username=username, password=password)

        config_commands = ['int gig0/1.7', 'description {0}'.format(facilities)]

        output = device.send_config_set(config_commands)
        print(output)
        print()
        output = device.send_command('show run int gig0/1.7')   
        print(output) 


        device.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for such behavior is because of this line.  You're basically telling it to output everything inside of facilities list.

```
config_commands = ['int gig0/1.7', 'description {0}'.format(facilities)]
```

If the value of the hosts and facilities are equal, for example 5 hosts has 5 facilities associate to it, you can probably do this.

```
import csv 
from netmiko import ConnectHandler  # Shouldn't be indented

# No difference where you're declaring this but by convention, it's easier to make changes to variable at the top than to look deep within the code
ipaddresses = []
facilities = []
platform = 'cisco_ios'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

    with open('NID3.csv') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

        for row in readCSV:
            ipaddresses.append (row[0])
            facilities.append (row[1])

    # If there are the same number of IP address to facility
    for i in range (len (ipaddresses)):
        device = ConnectHandler(device_type=platform, ip=ipaddresses [i], username=username, password=password)

        config_commands = ['int gig0/1.7', 'description {0}'.format(facilities [i])]
        print (config_commands)  # Suggest to print config_commands to confirm this is what you wanted
        print (device.send_config_set(config_commands))
        print()
        print (device.send_command('show run int gig0/1.7'))

        device.disconnect()
```

Comment: my man, TY.  That worked. Though to be honest I don't understand  exactly what is going on regarding the "for i in range (len "  and then using the [i] assuming that its just calling the i from the for statement.  Obvious im a python newb. Thanks again.

Comment: len (ipaddresses) gives me the number of IP address in the list.  If the list has 5 IP addresses then loop through it 5 times starting at i = 0 to i = 4.  The "i" here is the index for an element. Think of it this way, your CSV file contains a list of IP = [ip1, ip2, ip3].  When you call IP [i] for i = 0, you're calling ip1, when i = 1, you're calling ip2 and so forth.  Doing it this way you can loop through and get the values of both IPs and facilities in one run instead of looping through a list of IPs and then loop through a list of facility given that they both have equal lengths.